# Webpack 4 Error: Module parse failed sql-parser

Tags: reactjs, webpack, migration

I tried to migrate to webpack from 3, I changed loaders to rules, changed `System.import()` to `import()`, upgraded all the packages, changed the ts loader from awesome-typescript-loader and removed the new `webpack.NamedModulesPlugin()` but during the build I have this error:

```
    ERROR in ./node_modules/sql-parser/lib/compiled_parser.js
    Module parse failed: Invalid labeled declaration (394:26)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    |                 lstack.length = lstack.length - n;
    |             }
    |             _token_stack: function lex() {
    |                 var token;
    |                 token = lexer.lex() || EOF;
     @ ./node_modules/sql-parser/lib/parser.js 9:13-41
     @ ./node_modules/sql-parser/lib/sql_parser.js
     @ ./node_modules/sql-parser/index.js
     @ ./src/reducers/bands.js
     @ ./src/reducers/transients.js
     @ ./src/reducers/index.js
     @ ./src/main.js
     @ multi babel-polyfill ./src/main
```

How can I fix it?

EDIT 
webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path')
var webpack = require('webpack')

var paths = {
  src: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
  test: path.resolve(__dirname, '../test'),
  viewers: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src', 'components', 'viewers'),
  vendor: path.resolve(__dirname, '../vendor'),
  build: path.resolve(__dirname, '../build'),
  dist: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
}

var config = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill', path.resolve(paths.src, 'main')],
  output: {
    path: paths.build,
    pathinfo: true,
    filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[id].bundle.js',
    // publicPath: '/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
    alias: {
      'spread-view': path.resolve(paths.vendor, 'spread-view'),
      spreadjs: path.resolve(paths.vendor, 'spreadjs'),
    },
  },
  stats: {
    colors: true,
    reasons: true,
  },
  performance: {
    hints: false,
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts|\.tsx$/,
        include: [paths.src, paths.test],
        use: 'ts-loader',
      },
      {
        // enforce: 'pre',
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            options: {
              presets: ['es2015'],
            },
          },
        ],
        // use: 'source-map-loader',
        // include: [paths.src, paths.test],
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: [paths.src, paths.test],
        use: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        type: 'javascript/auto',
        use: 'json-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.yml$/,
        type: 'javascript/auto',
        use: ['json-loader', 'yaml-loader'],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(cur|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?.*)?$/,
        exclude: /\/favicon.ico$/,
        use: 'file-loader?name=media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
      },
      {
        test: /\/favicon.ico$/,
        include: paths.src,
        use: 'file-loader?name=favicon.ico?[hash:8]',
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: 'html-loader?attrs=false', //link:href
      },
      // SQLite script loader
      {
        test: /\.sql$/,
        use: 'sqlite-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
      $: 'jquery',
      jQuery: 'jquery',
      'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
    }),
    // new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin(),
  ],
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
  },
}

module.exports = {
  paths: paths,
  config: config,
}
```

webpack.config.debug.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var config = require('./webpack.config').config

module.exports = merge.smart(config, {
  bail: true,      
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',      
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('debug'),
      },
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      inject: true,
      template: 'index.html',
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeRedundantAttributes: true,
        useShortDoctype: true,
        removeEmptyAttributes: true,
        removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
        keepClosingSlash: true,
        minifyJS: true,
        minifyCSS: true,
        minifyURLs: true,
      },
    }),
  ],
})
```

Comment: show your `webpack` config..

Comment: @BasheerAhmedKharoti added as you ask

Comment: Shouldn't it be `presets: ['react', 'es2015'],`?

Comment: Yes you can read it in my babelrc `{
  "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0", "stage-2"],
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
}`

Comment: Same issue, any help about it?